# Integrate Complex Function. Is There a Faster Way

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{(z)^2(z-1)^3}.d\underline{z} = 0$$

I wanted to ask if there is a faster way rather than the Cauchy Integral Theorem(?)

The problem is partial fraction is taking too much time; I just need to know if I am missing a short cut?

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Yes, look at the residue at infinity, i.e. make substitution $1/z$

Comment: Residue theorem?

Comment: Right, Thanks! @user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the residue theorem, the integral
$$\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{z^2(z-1)^3}$$
is constant for any $R>1$, and by taking a very large $R$ we get

$$\left|\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{z^2(z-1)^3}\right|\leq \oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{|z|^2 |z-1|^3}\leq 2\pi R\cdot \frac{1}{R^2(R-1)^3} $$
hence the previous constant is zero.

Comment: I was able to calculate the Res at pole[1] which was -1. Could you please help me with pole [0]?
I am considering it of order 1 but I am getting an answer of infinity :/

Comment: @AliNaveed: there is no need to compute any residue: the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of them and the sum of them is zero by this ML argument. Anyway, the residue at the double pole $z=0$ is $-3$ and the residue at the triple pole $z=1$ is $3$.

Comment: The residue at a double pole can be computed through $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d}{dz}(z-z_0)^2 f(z)$ and the residue at a triple pole through $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(z-z_0)^3 f(z)$, or you may simply consider the Laurent series at $z=0$ and $z=1$.

Comment: In a neighbourhood of the origin $\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}=-1-3z-6z^2-10 z^3-\ldots$, hence $\text{Res}_{z=0}f(z)=-3$ is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks so much Jack! Youre the MVP. Im a rookie in complex analysis but getting the hang of it thanks to people like you!